# Swift / iOS: Error to post image to Pinterest

Tags: ios, swift, pinterest

Im getting this error while posting image to Pinterest

```
Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x144603bd0> { URL: https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/ } { status code: 401, headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 177;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Sun, 10 Jul 2016 19:38:00 GMT";
    "Pinterest-Generated-By" = "devplatform-devapi-prod-de3d740a";
    "Pinterest-Version" = bcdafd3;
    Server = nginx;
    "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
    "X-Pinterest-RID" = 480720869025;
    "X-Varnish" = 2958547338;
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b227374 61747573 223a2022 6661696c 75726522 2c202263 6f646522 3a20332c 2022686f 7374223a 20226465 76706c61 74666f72 6d2d6465 76617069 2d70726f 642d6465 33643734 3061222c 20226765 6e657261 7465645f 6174223a 20225375 6e2c2031 30204a75 6c203230 31362031 393a3338 3a303020 2b303030 30222c20 226d6573 73616765 223a2022 41757468 6f72697a 6174696f 6e206661 696c6564 2e222c20 22646174 61223a20 6e756c6c 7d>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unauthorized (401)}
```

Here is my code:

```
PDKClient.sharedInstance().createPinWithImage(image, link: NSURL(string:"http://domain"), onBoard: "MyBoard", description: caption, progress: {percent in
            print(percent)
            }, withSuccess: {PDKResponseObject in
                print("ok")
                print(PDKResponseObject.boards())
            }, andFailure: {error in
                print(error)
        })
```

Comment: Can you share how to make this call

Comment: @AlvinVarghese I've updated the code

Comment: Check this answer @TomSawyer

Answer (score 0):

Error 401 means one of the following.

```
 1.Authentication failed. 
 2.Authorization failed. 
 3.You are not permitted to access that resource.
```

Double check your permissions, check your session token expired or not.

So I think that there is nothing wrong with your code, or the request. It's something with the permissions you have in your `Pinterest` app.

Try changing the request URL from `http` to `https`.

Check the parameters you sending to `Pinterest`, check whether the `parameter names` are correct or not, as specified in `Pinterest` documentation. Also those parameters has the proper type of data, I mean do not pass `String` in the place of `Integer` value.
.

Comment: I know the 401 error means. I've read this from Pinterest SDK `Note: If you just want to Pin, there’s no need to authenticate! You can use CreatePin methods to Pin without authentication. This method redirects the user to the Pinterest app and shows the Pin creation window. If you want a customized experience where users Pin without leaving your app, you’ll need to authenticate.` So, there's no need to authenticate anything if i want to pin an image.

Comment: And the link can be any valid url, ive tried to changed to `https://www.pinterest.com` but it doesn't work either

Comment: Hmmm. That's strange.

Comment: Yep, do i need to wait until the app on pinterest get approved? Or i still can test it in development mode?

Comment: Could you please ask this on Pinterest support community?

Comment: Yep, i've posted but it seems noone care